# Is there a difference between "Leiche", "Leichnam", "Toter", or "Verstorbener"

Tags: word-usage, synonym

There are different German nouns for a corpse. Most used are

- die Leiche
- der Leichnam
- der/die Tote
- der/die Verstorbene

A [Google Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Leiche,Leichnam,Tote,Verstorbene&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=8&smoothing=3) shows a trend towards *"Tote"* being increasingly used over *"Leiche"*

[image]

but this does not say anything on the usage of any of these alternatives.

Are there differences in meaning or connotation? Is there a context where we would prefer to use one over the other term or are these all just interchangeable synonyms?

Comment: I'm not sure how Ngram handles sing./plural forms, but *Tote* is also a plural form: *Es gab drei Tote.*

Comment: It astonishes me, that there aren't any sharp peaks around the wars!

Comment: @Ludi: This may come from a [different propagandistic terminology](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Gefallene%2C+Heldentod&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=8&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CGefallene%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CHeldentod%3B%2Cc0) - and there still is a peak for *Tote*.

Comment: Good point. I chose a different magnification and it shows "Tote" was already declining before 1944 and for ww1 nothing out of the ordinary. Did I use ngram wrongly? https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Leiche%2CLeichnam%2CTote%2CVerstorbene&year_start=1912&year_end=1958&corpus=8&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CLeiche%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CLeichnam%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CTote%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CVerstorbene%3B%2Cc0

Comment: I am amazed at how quickly you guessed their favourite termini!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Generally, those cover two different aspects:

- **Leiche/Leichnam** are used to refer to the **dead body**. "Die Leiche wurde aus dem Autowrack geborgen."
  Both words are synonymous. Leichnam is a bit more formal. An undertaker wouldn't use Leiche in front of the deceased's relatives.
- **Toter/Verstorbener** are used to refer to the **person**, that has died. "Der Verstorbene war ein guter Freund von mir".
- **Toter** is used to refer to a person, that has been violently **killed** in an accident or by murder or in war.
- **Verstorbener** is used to refer to someone who has died (peacefully) of **natural causes** such as old age or an illness.

Comment: Good explanation! Additionally, one could state that it's usually no problem to substitute "Leiche" by "Verstorbener", but not the other way - talking about the "Leichnam/Leiche" in the context of a funeral would usually be quite crude.

Comment: According to the the [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Leichnam), "Leichnam" is on a higher stylistic level than "Leiche", and I agree. An example: I'd say "der Leichnam wurde aufgebahrt", not "die Leiche". Of course that's not a _major_ difference.

Comment: An additional note: "der Verstorbene" is more respectful than "der Tote"; the closest English equivalents are "dead person" and "deceased". Consider for example the sentence "Der Verstorbene bittet, von Blumenspenden abzusehen." It would be inappropriate to use "der Tote" in this context.

Answer (score 2):

"Tote" is the word used to describe people who died or got killed in the News on TV, Radio and other media.

Comment: +1 but still *"Leiche"* is also used in this context: *"Die Zahl der **Toten** nach dem Schiffsunglück in Italien steigt immer weiter: Taucher haben in dem Wrack der „Costa Concordia“ fünf **Leichen** entdeckt."*, [Focus](http://www.focus.de/panorama/welt/schifffahrt-mehr-tote-in-costa-concordia-gefunden_aid_703991.html)

Comment: shure it is used... to describe the bodies (other then the number of persons involved)... the use of these words in media could explain the statistics

Answer (score 1):

"Der Tote", "der Verstorbene" refer to a person who is unfortunately dead. "Die Leiche", "der Leichnam" refers to the physical remains.

"Der Tote" is not necessarily a corpse. For example, people killed in an explosion with no corpse left. Same for "der Verstorbene". You wouldn't use this word for someone dying in an explosion, only for natural / non-violent death, but the body could be cremated. "Leiche" or "Leichnam" means there is actually a corpse.

Answer (score -1):

A "Leichnam" is a dead human body, whereas a "Leiche" can also be a dead animal.